# Frontend - How to build vertical lines that span on all the page height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, frontend, bootstrap-5

What I am trying to achieve is very simple to understand. You have probably already seen this on other websites.

I need to have thin lines (1px) that match the columns borders and span all the way from the top to the bottom of the page. The should of course be always visibale and on top of the content.

I am working with bootsrap 5.

Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image: UI design with visibale lines matching columns]

What I have tried, is creating a container, with absolute position, 100% height with 6 different bordered columns, and assigned a higher z-index than the page content.

The visual result is perfect.

However, by being on top of the main content, **users cannot interact with the page as the container lays on top of everything**.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="container-fluid position-absolute top-0 z-990 h-100 d-none d-md-block">
   <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100">
         <div class="col-2 border-start border-end"></div>
         <div class="col-2 border-end"></div>
         <div class="col-2 border-end"></div>
         <div class="col-2 border-end"></div>
         <div class="col-2 border-end"></div>
         <div class="col-2 border-end"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just putting a border around the first div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a similar effect by using `background-image` css with `repeating-linear-gradient`.

```css
.bg-lines {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-image:  repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #dfdfdf, #dfdfdf 1px, #ffffff 1px, #ffffff);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body class="bg-lines">
  </body>
</html>
```

## UPDATE

You can add `select-event:none` css to the covered DOM. For example:

```css
.cover-lines {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-image:  repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #dfdfdf, #dfdfdf 1px, transparent 1px, transparent);
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Test</button>
    <div class="cover-lines"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ref: https://www.magicpattern.design/tools/css-backgrounds

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer! That would put the lines behind the content, such as images or sections that have a background color. I need the lines to be on top of everything as you can see from the design

Comment: You can use `select-events: none` css as the updated example. FYI.

Comment: Yes! I had no idea select-events: none worked that way as well, thanks!